# @refreshScope and @PropertySource how to?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

Anybody know if @RefreshScope, applied to class for reloading properties/yml files dinamically works with a configuration class annotated only with @PropertySource?
I have to refresh an external configuration file, but i cant do something like :

```
@Bean
@RefreshScope
public FileProperties refreshListConfig() {
 return new FileProperties();  //why ?
}


@Configuration //Configuration or new instance as above? 
@PropertySource("file:${path.properties}")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="multitenancy")
public class FileProperties {


    private List<DirProps> dir =new ArrayList<DirProps>();

    private String tenantsFilePath; 
..
class DirProps { ..}
...
}
```

I know that @RefreshScope doesn't work with @Configuration, but can I use @PropertySource without @Configuration?

Javadoc :
Annotation providing a convenient and declarative mechanism for adding a PropertySource to Spring's Environment. To be used in conjunction with @Configuration classes.

So, can't i use @RefreshScope without move external properties in application properties and removing @PropertySource and @Configuration annotations from FileProperties class? Do you know if exists a working approach without move the properties?
Thanks

Comment: `@PropertySource`: To be used in conjunction with @Configuration classes. You can find this info here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

Comment: So can't I use @RefreshScope only with application properties/yml, instead an external one? Is there a working solution without move properties from external to application properties?